# I got This error by upgrading to TensorFlow 2.1: "AttributeError: 'Operation' object has no attribute '_graph'"

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

My code is written under TensorFlow 2.0 and I run it on Ubuntu 18.04.04. The code is perfectly run with TensorFlow 2.0. But I need to use TensorFlow 2.1 because of some functionality of the TensorFlow_addones library. I upgrade the Tensorflow within my virtual environment by the command "conda install TensorFlow-gpu" and run the code. The code runs for the first epoch and saves the result but as soon as it starts next epoch, it stop and show this error.
If I downgrade the TensorFlow to 2.0, again the code run without any problem. Does anybody know what is the issue?
The problem is on CPU and GPU.

```
enter code here


with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    with tf.name_scope('setup'):
        psv_planes = inv_depths(min_depth, max_depth, num_psv_planes)
        mpi_planes = inv_depths(min_depth, max_depth, num_psv_planes)

        if frame == 'up':
            c_u = tf.expand_dims(sample[2][:int(.6 * img_height), :, :], axis=0)
            u1 = tf.expand_dims(sample[0], axis=0)
            u2 = tf.expand_dims(sample[3], axis=0)
        elif frame == 'low':
            c_l = tf.expand_dims(sample[2][-int(.6 * img_height):, :, :], axis=0)
            l1 = tf.expand_dims(sample[1], axis=0)
            l2 = tf.expand_dims(sample[4], axis=0)

    with tf.name_scope('model'):
        if frame == 'up':
            input_u = format_net_input(u1, u2, psv_planes, intrin_pos['pose_u2'], intrin_pos['pose_u1'],
                                       intrin_pos['intrinsics'])
            net_output_u = model(input_u)
            output = synthesize(net_output_u, u1, intrin_pos['pose_target'], mpi_planes, intrin_pos['intrinsics'])
        elif frame == 'low':
            input_l = format_net_input(l1, l2, psv_planes, intrin_pos['pose_l2'], intrin_pos['pose_l1'],
                                       intrin_pos['intrinsics'])
            net_output_l = model(input_l)
            output = synthesize(net_output_l, l1, intrin_pos['pose_target'], mpi_planes, intrin_pos['intrinsics'])

    with tf.name_scope('loss'):
        if frame == 'up':
            loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.l2_loss(output[:, :, :, :] - c_u[:, :, :, :]))
            print('upper loss is:{}'.format(loss))
        elif frame == 'low':
            loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.l2_loss(output[:, :, :, :] - c_l[:, :, :, :]))
            print('lower loss is:{}'.format(loss))
        # total_loss = total_loss_u + total_loss_l
        # print('total loss is:{}'.format(total_loss))

grads = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_weights)
optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_weights))
```

number of images:  7
2020-02-21 12:57:19.264638: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
2020-02-21 12:57:19.299154: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-02-21 12:57:19.300362: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1555] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:0b:00.0 name: Quadro RTX 8000 computeCapability: 7.5
coreClock: 1.77GHz coreCount: 72 deviceMemorySize: 47.46GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 625.94GiB/s
2020-02-21 12:57:19.300495: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
2020-02-21 12:57:19.301531: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10
2020-02-21 12:57:19.302656: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
2020-02-21 12:57:19.302800: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10
2020-02-21 12:57:19.303857: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10
2020-02-21 12:57:19.304423: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10
2020-02-21 12:57:19.306740: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2020-02-21 12:57:19.306856: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-02-21 12:57:19.308102: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-02-21 12:57:19.309243: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1697] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-02-21 12:57:19.309477: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA
2020-02-21 12:57:19.335253: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:94] CPU Frequency: 3593090000 Hz
2020-02-21 12:57:19.335853: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x55fbe0d89300 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-02-21 12:57:19.335875: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
2020-02-21 12:57:19.336100: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-02-21 12:57:19.338287: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1555] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:0b:00.0 name: Quadro RTX 8000 computeCapability: 7.5
coreClock: 1.77GHz coreCount: 72 deviceMemorySize: 47.46GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 625.94GiB/s
2020-02-21 12:57:19.338321: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
2020-02-21 12:57:19.338333: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10
2020-02-21 12:57:19.338344: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
2020-02-21 12:57:19.338354: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10
2020-02-21 12:57:19.338365: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10
2020-02-21 12:57:19.338375: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10
2020-02-21 12:57:19.338385: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2020-02-21 12:57:19.338466: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-02-21 12:57:19.340744: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-02-21 12:57:19.342952: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1697] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-02-21 12:57:19.342984: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
2020-02-21 12:57:19.420445: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1096] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2020-02-21 12:57:19.420465: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1102]      0 
2020-02-21 12:57:19.420469: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] 0:   N 
2020-02-21 12:57:19.420626: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-02-21 12:57:19.421815: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-02-21 12:57:19.422990: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:981] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-02-21 12:57:19.424134: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1241] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 46004 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: Quadro RTX 8000, pci bus id: 0000:0b:00.0, compute capability: 7.5)
2020-02-21 12:57:19.425373: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x55fbe2365e90 initialized for platform CUDA (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-02-21 12:57:19.425380: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Quadro RTX 8000, Compute Capability 7.5
rm: invalid option -- '/'
Try 'rm --help' for more information.
Initializing from scratch.
epoch 0 is started
7
image number: 0
2020-02-21 12:57:20.660563: I tensorflow/core/kernels/cuda_solvers.cc:159] Creating CudaSolver handles for stream 0x55fbe2353fb0
2020-02-21 12:57:20.660662: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10
2020-02-21 12:57:20.871250: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10
2020-02-21 12:57:21.021126: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10
2020-02-21 12:57:21.155054: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
upper loss is:79981.0234375
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/monajemd/.conda/envs/facetvision/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/array_grad.py:563: _EagerTensorBase.cpu (from tensorflow.python.framework.ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use tf.identity instead.
lower loss is:105275.3515625
image number: 1
upper loss is:123967.109375
lower loss is:90015.671875
image number: 2
upper loss is:74442.25
lower loss is:80841.8125
image number: 3
upper loss is:151827.796875
lower loss is:56213.5546875
image number: 4
upper loss is:107546.7890625
lower loss is:39292.203125
image number: 5
upper loss is:116781.0
lower loss is:50309.76953125
image number: 6
upper loss is:74282.4609375
lower loss is:35550.5
saving model
2020-02-21 12:57:33.090168: W tensorflow/python/util/util.cc:319] Sets are not currently considered sequences, but this may change in the future, so consider avoiding using them.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/monajemd/.conda/envs/facetvision/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.py:1786: calling BaseResourceVariable.**init** (from tensorflow.python.ops.resource_variable_ops) with constraint is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
If using Keras pass *_constraint arguments to layers.
epoch 1 is started
7
image number: 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/monajemd/Desktop/facetvision/main.py", line 320, in 
    main(path)
  File "/home/monajemd/Desktop/facetvision/main.py", line 263, in main
    sample, frame, optimizer, intrin_pos)
  File "/home/monajemd/Desktop/facetvision/main.py", line 172, in train_and_checkpoint
    net_output_u = model(input_u)
  File "/home/monajemd/.conda/envs/facetvision/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 822, in **call**
    outputs = self.call(cast_inputs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/monajemd/.conda/envs/facetvision/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/network.py", line 717, in call
    convert_kwargs_to_constants=base_layer_utils.call_context().saving)
  File "/home/monajemd/.conda/envs/facetvision/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/network.py", line 891, in _run_internal_graph
    output_tensors = layer(computed_tensors, **kwargs)
  File "/home/monajemd/.conda/envs/facetvision/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 822, in **call**
    outputs = self.call(cast_inputs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/monajemd/.conda/envs/facetvision/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/layers/convolutional.py", line 209, in call
    outputs = self._convolution_op(inputs, self.kernel)
  File "/home/monajemd/.conda/envs/facetvision/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/nn_ops.py", line 1135, in **call**
    return self.conv_op(inp, filter)
  File "/home/monajemd/.conda/envs/facetvision/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/nn_ops.py", line 640, in **call**
    return self.call(inp, filter)
  File "/home/monajemd/.conda/envs/facetvision/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/nn_ops.py", line 616, in _with_space_to_batch_call
    block_shape=self.dilation_rate)
  File "/home/monajemd/.conda/envs/facetvision/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 3282, in required_space_to_batch_paddings
    [input_shape, block_shape]):
  File "/home/monajemd/.conda/envs/facetvision/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py", line 6185, in name_scope
    return graph_value.graph.name_scope(name)
  File "/home/monajemd/.conda/envs/facetvision/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py", line 416, in graph
    return self._op.graph
  File "/home/monajemd/.conda/envs/facetvision/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py", line 2225, in graph
    return self._graph
AttributeError: 'Operation' object has no attribute '_graph'

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: show the code and the complete error

Comment: I update the post. complete error and the part that I got error

Comment: I figured it out that this Error is gone if I am not saving the model after each epoch.
I used tf.save_model.save(model, path). If I comment it then, then it will no error.

Then I use model.save(path), which is keras version of the saving model, it has no error.